# Does anyone know how I can add a table to a view controller?

Tags: xcode, rows

I want to create a literal table (mini) with rows and columns. Something like in the picture attached.

There isn't anything remotely similar to the table I want in the library on Xcode. Whenever googling all the search results are related to table controllers and stuff, which I'm not looking for.

[image: A table like this is what I intend to do.]

Comment: Use a UITableVIew. You will need a custom cell class with the needed columns.